# Exclude a specific td from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

hello there I have an `HTML` table which I want to exclude a specific `td` from it and i dont know how.

**HTML :**

```
 <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
                           cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>row</th>
                            <th>title</th>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th> Type </th>
                            <th> date</th>
                            <th>func</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                            
                            {% for item in knowledges %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.KnowledgeTitle}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.CreatorUserID.get_full_name }}</td>
                                    <td>                             
                                        {% if item.Type == 1 %}
                                         Show Something...
                                        {% endif %}               
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="{{ item.CreateDate }}{{ forloop.counter }}"></td>
                                    <td id="excluded">
                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/KnowledgeView/{{ item.KnowledgeCode }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-eye">Show</i> </a>
                                        <button title="show" type="button" onclick="getClickID(this.id)" id="{{item.KnowledgeCode}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" >Click</button>                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
```

So basicly i want to exclude the second `td`  `<td>{{item.KnowledgeTitle}}</td>` which is Title.

```
function htmlToCSV(html, filename) {
    var data = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
            
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
                
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                row.push(cols[j].innerText);
        }
                
        data.push(row.join(","));       
    }

    downloadCSVFile(data.join("\n"), filename);
```

> Please dont get confused with some Django-template-tags

Comment: Please click [edit] then the `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] WITHOUT TEMPLATING, just relevant JS, HTML and CSS

Comment: thought maybe there would a way in jq to skip some js code @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Why not skip it on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can place a class on the cells to be excluded and then target them with `:not()` in your `querySelectorAll()` selector.

Also note that your code can be made more succinct by using `map()`. Try this:

```js
function htmlToCSV(html, filename) {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  let csv = Array.from(rows).map(row => {
    return Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td:not(.export-exclude), th:not(.export-exclude)')).map(cell => cell.innerText).join(',');
  });
  console.log(csv);
  
  //downloadCSVFile(data.join("\n"), filename);
}

htmlToCSV();
```

```html
<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row</th>
      <th class="export-exclude">title</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th> Type </th>
      <th> date</th>
      <th>func</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="export-exclude">item.KnowledgeTitle 1</td>
      <td>item.CreatorUserID.get_full_name 1</td>
      <td>
        Show Something 1...
      </td>
      <td id=""></td>
      <td id="excluded">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/KnowledgeView/{{ item.KnowledgeCode }}">
          <i class="fa fa-eye">Show</i>
        </a>
        <button title="show" type="button" onclick="getClickID(this.id)" id="{{item.KnowledgeCode}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="export-exclude">item.KnowledgeTitle 2</td>
      <td>item.CreatorUserID.get_full_name 2</td>
      <td>
        Show Something 2...
      </td>
      <td id=""></td>
      <td id="excluded">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/KnowledgeView/{{ item.KnowledgeCode }}">
          <i class="fa fa-eye">Show</i>
        </a>
        <button title="show" type="button" onclick="getClickID(this.id)" id="{{item.KnowledgeCode}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, the `html` argument of your function does nothing and can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an identifier to the element you don't want to select then select like this `querySelectorAll("td:not(.excluded-class)");`

Comment: do i need to add class for the td ? or can i handle it with id?

Comment: class worked ty

Comment: You can do either, querySelector works on CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

exclude `td` and `th` from the table using `querySelectorAll("td:not(.excluded-class),th:not(.excluded-class)");`

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your function to exclude (not to include in your data.row) like this:

```
htmlToCSV(html, filename) {
    var data = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            if (j != 1) {
                row.push(cols[j].innerText);
            }
        }
    }

    data.push(row.join(","));
}
```

Comment: This tends to be a bad idea as it relies on the order of DOM elements remaining consistent. If somebody else went to change the HTML they probably wouldn't be expecting this code to exist.

Comment: Off-course, but it resolves the issue as per the current context; Wouldn't suggest to modify more code or replace all the code when ONE line can solve the problem?

Comment: Your one line that solves the problem could cause hours of future debugging so yes I would suggest that. Either way you don't need to replace everything, you can change this in a quick way that wouldn't cause issues if you reordered your HTML so it's a moot point.